# Como funciona el método "HashWithIndifferentAccess" en ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Deseo implementar el en Ruby on Rails una forma de acceder a las claves de un hash mediante un :símbolo o un "string" indiferentemente de que metodo se utilice, he intentado con HashWithIndifferentAccess pero aun me arroja todo el contenido del hash, el objeto al cual deseo acceder es `subject { JSON.parse(response.body) }`

```
      context 'when post is public' do
      before { get "/posts/#{other_user_post.id}", headers: auth_header }
      context 'payload' do
        subject { JSON.parse(response.body) }
        it { is_expected.to include(:id) }
      end
```

Comment: ¿Pero que te está entregando  `JSON.parse(response.body)`? ¿has probado con `it { is_expected.to include('id') }`?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Conseguí solucionarlo, colocare la respuesta en un rato.

Answer (score 0):

Logre la funcionalidad que estaba buscando al incluir un método privado con la función with_indifferent_access

```
      Context 'when post is public' do
          before { get "/posts/#{other_user_post.id}", headers: auth_header }
          context 'payload' do
            subject { payload }
            it { is_expected.to include(:id) }
          end
      end 

      private

      def payload
         JSON.parse(response.body).with_indifferent_access
      end
```